# Close Processes in "Check for running processes" does not work correctly on Windows

Tags: java-8, install4j

there is a little problem with closing running processes (without an ui).

We're writing an application which doesn't have an (main) ui except a tray icon for opening preferences.

I added a "Check for running processes" with "Allow soft close and termination" option to the installation process.

If I try to install a new version of my application I get the message, that there is a running process of my application, but if I click on "Close processes", nothing happens, only on "Terminate processes" it will be killed.

If I open the preferences window of my application the window will be closed but not the process itself.

On macOS it is working fine.

We're using latest install4J-6 version.

Do I have to set another option or do I have to launch a script which will terminate my application?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soft close is not guaranteed to succeed. On Windows it works like this:

- "Soft close" posts a `WM_CLOSE` message to all visible windows of a process. This may not work if the application does not cooperate, for example if a modal dialog is being displayed.
- "Terminate" operates on the process and calls `TerminateProcess` which succeeds without the cooperation of the application.

Comment: Is there any other way to soft close a running (background) process except using "Allow termination"?

Comment: You can use the WinProcesses API in a "Run script" action: https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/windows/WinProcesses.html

Comment: Unfortunately I found nothing extra in API. 
@IngoKegel is there any chance you can add an option to send `SIGINT` to the process?

Comment: This is an API for Windows processes. Windows does not support POSIX signals and there is no Windows API to send a "CTRL-C" signal to a process that does not have a console.